# Make windows stay in desktop area

Tags: macos, finder, desktop

When I move any Finder or application window on the screen, they won't pass the upper desktop border. When I move them to the left, to the right, or to the desktop bottom, they are pushed outside of the visible area.

Is it possible to change this behaviour?
How can I make Finder hold all windows in the desktop area instead?

Comment: You used to be able to turn off spaces, but I don't you can any more. Windows can move off screen to move between spaces. Moving up should activate Mission Control starting El Capitan. If you only use one Space "Desktop" then you should probably  start using more, it's very helpful.

Comment: OK, moving windows between Spaces would be a problem with windows locked in the desktop area. So it would be nice if one could make sure that windows can be moved within the desktop boundaries only with a special key pressed simultaneously. That is (would be): Moving windows while the Alt key is pressed makes them stick to the Desktop area - for example.

Comment: Sounds good, now you should contact Apple. However, if you feel neglected by the Tech Giant look into third party window managing applications like [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/).